# removing characters from list elements in python

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting content with the help of scrapy into an array. Each element has the unwanted characters ": " inside which I would like to remove as efficient as possible.

```
v = response.xpath('//div[@id="tab"]/text()').extract()
>>> v
['Marke:', 'Modell:']
>>> for i in v : re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', i)
... 
'Marke'
'Modell'
```

Now that seems to work, but how can I retain the result?
In my code, `v` hasn't changed:

```
>>> v
['Marke:', 'Modell:']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> v = response.xpath('//div[@id="tab"]/text()').extract()
>>>
>>> import re
>>> v = [re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', i) for i in v]
>>> v
['Marke', 'Modell']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that pulling in `regex` for this is a little overkill: use the string `replace` method:

```
v = ['Marke:', 'Modell:']
v = [str.replace(':', '') for str in v]
print(v)
```

Output:

```
['Marke', 'Modell']
```